# Why does a space cause the remembered pattern in sed to output different things

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, regex-greedy

I'm trying to get the value of the value entry in this xml line via terminal so I'm using sed.

```
abcs='<param name="abc" value="bob3" no_but_why="4"/>'

echo $abcs | sed -e 's/.*value="\(.*\)" .*/\1/'
echo $abcs | sed -e 's/.*value="\(.*\)".*/\1/'
```

The output is:

```
bob3
bob3" no_but_why="4
```

Why does the second way without the space cause more than just what I wanted to be printed out? Why would the \1 be affected by that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see difference is use of greedy pattern `.*` in second regex after `"` without space.

Reason why it is behaving differently because there is a double quote after `no_but_why=` as well and `.*` being a greedy pattern is matching until last `"` before `/>` in second regex.

In your first regex `"\(.*\)"` is matching only `"bob3"` because there is a space after this which makes regex engine prevent `.*` matching till last double quote in input.

**To avoid this situation** you should be using negated character class instead of greedy matching.

Consider these sed command examples:

```
sed -e 's/.*value="\([^"]*\)" .*/\1/' <<< "$abcs"
bob3

sed -e 's/.*value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' <<< "$abcs"
bob3
```

Now you can see both command are producing same output `bob3` because **negated character class** `[^"]*` will match until it gets next `"` not till the very last `"` in input as the case with `.*`.

Comment: So what do I do to make it only match the first such occurrence?

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense!